# How did Zeon militarize before the One Year War?

Tags: mobile-suit-gundam

My question is how was the Principality of Zeon was able to militarize itself so quickly right under the Earth Federation's nose. I've only watched the Mobile Suit Gundam movie trilogy, so it may have been brought up in the full tv series?

It just seems to me that the Federation government would have taken steps to nip Zeon militarization in the bud before it became a significant problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the full TV series has the details for the Principality of Zeon to rise to power either. If you are really interested, you can read the comic version called "**Mobile Suit Gundam ORIGINS**", it has detailed the history of the colonies and the rising of Zeon.

But I would give you a concise summary in here.

#### Secrecy

Although the Federation seems to have absolute power on the colonies, the Principality of Zeon actually have some kind of independence in the L3 Colonies. Before the war, the Zeon have built a secret dark colony, for manufacturing their arsenal, including their warships and Mobile Suits. It was kept well hidden to the Federation for the years of preparation. This gives the Zeon to have sufficient military power to have war with the Federation.

Moreover, most of the military arsenal in the early days are designated as civilian use, in order to sneak under the Federation's nose. For example, the Mobile Suit was originally branded as exoskeleton for Lunar or asteroid mining, and Musai-class Cruiser was manufactured as civilian transporter (which could be quickly modified to Battlecruiser/Carrier for MS).

Therefore, the Zeon would quickly militarize their asset without the Federation noticing.

#### Underestimation

Although the Federation espionage have indication that the Mobile Suit could be used for military, the concern was quickly dismissed for the High Command, because the war standard for the time is to have "Bigger Ship, Bigger Gun", pretty much mirroring the early days of WWII. As the Federation have most of large warships and cannons with extreme power and precision, they would not except Zeon has the capability to undergo a full scale war.

However, the introduction of Minovsky Particle cause the radar and tracking system to render useless, limiting the main advantage of most of the Federation arsenal. While the performance of the Mobile Suit is proved to be exceptionally well during early days of the war (One Week Battle), the Federation is not able to react properly till to the mid/late period of the war. This cause the Federation to lose the L2 and L5 Colonies, even Zeon has only one-third of its military power (The strategy success from the Zeon Command also come into play though, but this would be another topic).

I might not cover all of the details and reasons here, but I think these are some of main reasons summarized. Please comment below if you could provide more details, I would add them in the article.

Comment: Interesting. So Zeon used its limited autonomy to secretly build up a military force and then disguised that force as civilian technology. It actually makes sense as Germany followed a similar track in rearming in the 1930s. Certain bombers (such as the Heinkel He 111) were built as civilian transports but were really intended for military use.

Comment: In that case, it seems to me that a major factor leading to the war was negligence on the part of the Federation. Sort of like how the Allies turned a blind eye to German rearmament, the Federation dismissed Zeon as a pushover and paid dearly for it.

Comment: The show did have a lot of references/symbolizing to WW2. The realism of the series make it become a major hit.